# odoo v8 about states selection field

Tags: odoo

My question is that I made a field of type selection and in this field I try to show the states of my country to the user but it show me just two states but in code I add more than three states at the beginning but in fact I want from the field to show me 22 states how I can do this.
this is the code

```
state = fields.Selection(string="state", selection=[('s', 'Sanaa'), ('t', 'Taiz'), ('a', 'Amran')],
         required=False, )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should use res.country.state? You meant that your selection has X options but only 2 of them are displayed? Don't you have any domain in view definition?

Comment: i try to use res.country.state but it still show me the same result and I do not have any domain in view definition.

Comment: can you attach a print screen?